# Multiple parameter to route error laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I have method in my controller (singleProduct):

```
    public function singleProduct($slug)
{
   $product= Product::where('slug','=', $slug)->first();
   return view('public.product.show')->withProduct($product);
}
```

And my route is:

```
Route::get('/{category}/{slug}',['as' => 'single.product', 'uses' => 'LinkController@singleProduct']);
```

My code in view:

```
<a href="{{ route('single.product', $product->category, $product->slug) }}">{{$product->title}}</a>
```

Though i have passed both required parameter for route.My route is returning an error of:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: single.product] [URI: {category}/{slug}].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way for defining route params is like:

```
route('single.product', ['category' => $product->category, 'slug' => $product->slug])
```

So your route in view will be as:

```
<a href="{{ route('single.product', ['category' => $product->category, 'slug' => $product->slug]) }}">{{$product->title}}</a>
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

In route definition you have slug and category, but in method you get actually just the slug, so maybe adding $category to singleProduct will help:

```
public function singleProduct($category, $slug)
{
   $product= Product::where('slug','=', $slug)->first();
   return view('public.product.show')->withProduct($product);
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use both parameters in method also ?

Comment: yes, if you defined both on the route then both needs to be on the action method... 
you could turn them to optional parameters, i.e.

 Route::get('/{category}/{slug?}',['as' => 'single.product', 'uses' => 'LinkController@singleProduct']); and then function delcaration would look like 
singleProduct($category, $slug = 'no-slug')

Comment: I need both parameters for link building.

Comment: I modified my method to accept both parameter still no progress